# Django assertTemplateUsed() throws exception with Jinja templates

Tags: python, django, testing, jinja2, assert

When I try to run this test:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.test import Client

class StatisticTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

    def test_schedule_view(self):
        url = reverse('schedule')
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'schedule.html')
```

I get AssertionError: No templates used to render the response.

It's my view:

```
class Schedule(View):
    def get(self, request):
        games = add_team_info(query.get_current_schedule())
        if games is not []:
             available_schedules = generate_schedule_list(games[0]["season_type"], games[0]["week"])
             is_available = True
        else:
             available_schedules = []
             is_available = False
        return render_to_response("schedule.html", 
                              {"games": games, "available_schedules": available_schedules, "is_available": is_available})
```

and urls.py:

```
url(r'^schedule/$', views.Schedule.as_view(), name='schedule'),
```

Comment: Where is the template located in your project directory?

Comment: in folder "templates". I write it in setting.py (TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django_jinja.backend.Jinja2",
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'templates'),
        ],)

Comment: Is there a reason you need to alter the templates directory? You should just be able to create a templates directory in your application for Django to find.  Your assertion error is very similar to the one found in the Django TDD book: http://www.tdd-django-tutorial.com/tutorial/3/ This indicates that Django cannot find the template.

Comment: I create templates directory in my application, move my template to this directory , and add it in settings.py, but I get the same error.

Comment: Can you try with the original settings.py template directory settings?

Comment: It's not supported https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24622 . See discussion for more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that `assertTemplateUsed` only works with Django templates, not with Jinja templates.

There's an open ticket [24622](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24622) about this issue.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I try to print response.templates and it print empty list. Thanks